# Define a maximum number of line in a div

Tags: html, css

I create a  with a text inside but the text is too large for the div :
[image]

How can I stop the text when the div is stopping ?

Comment: set a height and make that div scrollable :)

Comment: Do you simply want the box to scroll or cut off the text? If so: [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) is the keyword you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is [line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp). It works on all browsers except IE11.

You can control how many lines want to show. Optionally, you can expand the content on hover / active / focus.

```css
.content {
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content:hover,
.content:active,
.content:focus {
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
}
```

```html
<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use to achieve that the `overflow` property in css:

```css
div {
  border: solid black 3px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Please take a look at the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div class='text'>
*your text here*
</div>

<style>
.text{
overflow-y: scroll;
height:400px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific height to the `div` and then use `overflow : auto;` to resolve your issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div.ex3 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 100%;
      height: 110px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ex3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
    nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>


</body>

</html>
```